# for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $r \gt n$, calculate: $\int_{\partial^+B(0,r)} z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $D=B(0,r)$ s.t. $r \gt n \in \mathbb{N}$, calculate:

$$\int_{\partial^+D} z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}$$

for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $0$ is a pole. Now, I want to write the Laurent series of the function in $z_0 =0$, to use the residue theorem, any hint about that?

**Edit**

Tried a solution after the hints:

$$ z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{u^n}e^u = \frac{1}{u^n}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{u^k}{k!} = \sum_{t=-n}^{+\infty} \frac{u^t}{(n+t)!} = \sum_{t=-n}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{z^t(n+t)!} $$

So $c_{-1} = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, hence the integral is equal to $\frac{2\pi i}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: Change $z$ to $\frac 1 z$ in the series for $e^{z}$.

Comment: No, $z=0$ is not a pole! It's an essential singularity.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by $\partial^+D$. If my guess is correct that's not a closed curve, so the Residue Theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes, you're right, the limit for $z \to 0$ doesn't exist. Btw, it means the boundary of $D$ in the positive orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Perform the substitution $u=\frac{1}{z}$ and then use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)